# Enums to implement different methods in Java

Tags: java, enums

Suppose I constructed the following class

```
public enum OptimizationAlgorithmType {

    VANILLA(new HashMap<String, Double>()) {

        private final static String ETA = "eta";
        private Double eta = null;

        public OptimizationAlgorithmType setEta(Double eta) {
            this.eta = eta;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, Double> getHyperarameters() {
            this.map.put(ETA, eta);
            return this.map;
        }       
    }, 

    MOMENTUM(new HashMap<String, Double>()) {

        private final static String ALPHA = "alpha";
        private final static String BETA = "beta";

        private Double alpha = null;
        private Double beta = null;

        public OptimizationAlgorithmType setAlpha(Double alpha) {
            this.alpha = alpha;
            return this;
        }

        public OptimizationAlgorithmType setBeta(Double beta) {
            this.beta = beta;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, Double> getHyperarameters() {
            this.map.put(ALPHA, alpha);
            this.map.put(BETA, beta);
            return this.map;
        }
    };

    protected Map<String, Double> map;

    private OptimizationAlgorithmType(Map<String, Double> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public abstract Map<String, Double> getHyperarameters();    
}
```

My goal was to construct an API that when I select a specif Enum then different methods would be available. For example

```
MultiThreadBackpropagation backpropagation = new MultiThreadBackpropagation(feedForward)
        .setNumberThreads(10)
        .setBatch(5)
        .setEpochs(100)
        .setOptimizer(OptimizationAlgorithmType.VANILLA.setEta(0.001));
```

Or

```
MultiThreadBackpropagation backpropagation = new MultiThreadBackpropagation(feedForward)
        .setNumberThreads(10)
        .setBatch(5)
        .setEpochs(100)
        .setOptimizer(OptimizationAlgorithmType.MOMENTUM.setAlpha(0.01).setBeta(0.99));
```

Unfortunately, this is not allowed. The ide warns about the unused methods (i.e.: `setEta()`)- and the methods are not available at all to select from the specific enum.

Is there a trick I can use to get the desired API?

Thanks

**Edit** Added an alternative answer below

Comment: It really looks like you shouldn't be using enum for this. In addition to the problem you've asked about, you're also using the enums mutably which is pretty dubious. It seems like you should write some normal builders or something instead. (And for the record, there's no trick here to get this working. Just don't use enums.)

Comment: @Radiodef I was just trying to present the api a certain way - I can make it work with other means.

Comment: You can present the API in the same identical way for your clients by using public static final fields instead that enum values.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with some better

First an interface, then the two parameter classes that implement the interface

```
public interface Hyperparameter {...}   

public enum VanillaParameter implements Hyperparameter {
        ETA {

            @Override
            public Double getValue() {
                return this.etaValue;
            }

            @Override
            public void setValue(Double value) {

                if (value == null) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Parameter value cannot be set to null!");
                }
                this.etaValue = value;
            }
        };
        protected Double etaValue = 0.005;
    }

    public enum MomentumParameter implements Hyperparameter {
    ...
    }
```

Now add the main enum class

```
    public enum OptimizationType {

        VANILLA{
            private VanillaParameter eta = VanillaParameter.ETA;

            @Override
            public Hyperparameter get(Hyperparameter parameter) {
                switch ((VanillaParameter) parameter) {
                case ETA: return this.eta;
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public OptimizationType set(Hyperparameter parameter, Double value) {

                switch ((VanillaParameter) parameter) {
                case ETA: 
                    this.eta.setValue(value);
                    break;
                }
                return OptimizationType.VANILLA;
            }
        },
        ...
}
```

And the API looks really nice in my opinion and resembles my initial intention. Look forward to suggestions

```
MultiThreadBackpropagation backpropagation = new MultiThreadBackpropagation.BackpropagationBuilder(feedForward)
        .setBatch(5)
        .setEpochs(100)
        .setThreads(10)
        .setOptimizer(OptimizationType.MOMENTUM
                .set(MomentumParameter.ALPHA, 0.001)
                .set(MomentumParameter.BETA, 0.92))
        .build();
```

Comment: every time you call: set(Hyperparameter parameter, Double value) , you change the value of eta for everyone who uses OptimizationType.VANILLA

Comment: @RayTayek Yes very true and very problematic.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try something like:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class So54067082enums_to_implement_different_methods_in_java {
    enum Type {
        vanilla(new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"eta"}))),
        momentum(new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"alpha","beta"})));
        Type(Set<String> names) {
            this.names=names;

        }
        final Set<String> names;
    }
    static class ParameterSet {
        ParameterSet(Type type) {
            this.type=type;
        }
        Double get(String name) {
            if(type.names.contains(name))
                return map.get(name);
            else throw new RuntimeException("oops");
        }
        void set(String name,Double value) {
            if(type.names.contains(name))
                map.put(name,value);
            else throw new RuntimeException("oops");
        }
        @Override public String toString() {
            return "ParameterSet [type="+type+", map="+map+"]";
        }
        final Type type;
        private final SortedMap<String,Double> map=new TreeMap<>();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ParameterSet parameterSet=new ParameterSet(Type.vanilla);
        parameterSet.set("eta",.01);
        System.out.println(parameterSet);
        ParameterSet parameterSet2=new ParameterSet(Type.momentum);
        parameterSet2.set("alpha",.1);
        parameterSet2.set("beta",.9);
        System.out.println(parameterSet2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you couldn't just use a less naive approach to the problem:

```
class OptimizationAlgorithm {
  public static class Vanilla implements OptimizationAlgorithm {
    public Vanilla setAlpha(float a) {
      return this;
    }

    public Vanilla setBeta(float a) {
      return this;
    }
  }

  public static Vanilla vanilla() { return new Vanilla(); }
}

backpropagation.setOptimizer(OptimizationAlgorithm.vanilla().setAlpha(0.05f).setBeta(0.10f));
```

A lot less boilerplate code, no mutable static instances problem and basically the same interface from the outside.